# Question which cannot have proper answer

Tags: support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Broken suspend-to-ram mode](https://superuser.com/questions/1063980/broken-suspend-to-ram-mode)

It appears that the problem I faced in question above is caused by firmware, and not by software, as I thought earlier. Thus, the question cannot have proper answer. Shall I detete it, or do something different?

Comment: If everyone knew the right answer initially, the site wouldn't have any questions.  It could be useful to others with a similar problem if you write your own answer describing what the problem turned out to be and your solution.  Accept your own answer and people will know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: How do you know it is the firmware?  Have you actually resolved the problem?  If you know, without any uncertainty, that there is no solution then that *can* be an answer.

Comment: I had a call with ASUS support today and they told this issue isn't very rare, and manifests itself on Windows system too. And it's almost certainly caused by firmware bug. Thanks both of you for your responses, I will answer it as soon as I'll have chance to verify/bust it. Most probably I'll have fun time flashing BIOS.

Comment: You should only delete questions you cannot fixed.  Just keep it mind, deleted questions are used in the calculation, to determine if you can or cannot ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

Post your own answer once you've confirmed its the firmware. Just because you thought it was software may not mean it was, and if someone *else* suspects the same thing, being pointed at the firmware is handy.

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple solutions corresponding to those symptoms. Therefore, I would post an answer explaining the actual problem **and the steps used to repair it**. If you're not sure whether your answer is useful, or if you want to invite other users to fill it in, making it [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/295684) would be appropriate if you have sufficient privileges.

It looks like you've made an effort to describe your full environment (good job!), so it wouldn't be *completely* impossible for someone skilled to quickly know that the firmware was at fault. Therefore, I see no reason to delete it.

<sup>Note: As alluded to in the comments by Ramhound, continually deleting your questions is a way to get automatically banned from asking questions. The only person who can save you from that state is yourself, and only with great effort.</sup>